# Does Watir work with Ironruby(or .Net in any other way)?

Tags: .net, ironruby, watir

So I've been trying to get Watir setup with Ironruby so I can use Watir instead of Watin(I just dont like Watin that much), the only issue is I cant seem to get it working, and searches bring me to some conflicting info. Some say it wont work, others say use igem.

Right now I'm running VS 2008(3.5), and Ironruby 1.0. Every time I run

```
igem install watir
```

I get an error saying I need to install .NET Framwork v4.0.30319

I get the same error if I use Ironruby 1.1.

Has anyone here gotten Watir to work in .Net? Or is it true it cannot be run from it?

Comment: I believe Microsoft ended support for IronRuby so I would take another look at WatiN

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Watir (for IE at least) will require the Ruby implementation to support native gems.  IronRuby does not support native gems.  It will not work and I believe JRuby has the same issue.

Answer (score 1):

Watir doesn't support ironruby. I made some attempts to have [Vapir](http://vapir.org/) support IronRuby, but gave up before completion due to lack of interest. And, now with IronRuby's main guy having left microsoft, that's probably going to be dead soon enough.

Answer (score 1):

I've never tried Watir with IronRuby, if someone has time to take a look at it, that would be interesting. IronRuby isn't dead, it's on github and still be worked on. Without the financial and technical backing of MS, it's certainly going to be more difficult, but I'm not one to count it dead yet. :) If it was a stock, I'd go with 'hold', wait and see how it progresses.

Answer (score 1):

Did you try IronRuby with [WatiN](http://www.ruby-forum.com/topic/195764#853750)? That seems to work.